# How to execute Python files from Python?

Tags: python, shell, subshell

I am attempting to execute Python files from a deconstructed file.

```
import utils
import os
print(utils.fileReader('holderFile.py'))
test = utils.fileReader('holderFile.py')
for i in test:
    if(i == ''):
        os.system('')  #this allows for it to read spaces in the file
    else:
        os.system('python3 ' + i)
        print(i)
os.system('python3 exit()')
#os.system("sudo python scale1.py")


print('Done')
```

It is running but it gives me this error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
def simpleAdder(i, j):
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
    return (i+j)
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
simpleAdder(5, 8)
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

`holderFile.py` is just a simple addition method

```
def simpleAdder(i, j):
    return (i+j)

simpleAdder(5, 8)
```

How would I go about getting a Python file to execute properly using a method similar to this, or what would you suggest I use?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: What does `utils.fileReader()` do? Why aren't you `import`ing it?

Comment: I'm sending information over the socket and have to break it down into a list and then re assemble it into code. there is a valid reason for doing this, its not as simple as importing it.

Comment: file reader is a method i created to read files

Comment: Does `python3 <some Python code>` usually work?

Comment: its ok I figured out an alternative and answered below, it normally works, it is just weird how its working. Thanks for helping though :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import holderFile
```

Or:

```
from holderFile import simpleAdder
```

And then call `simpleAdder` normally.

Comment: I'm sending information over the socket and have to break it down into a list and then re assemble it into code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and will leave the thread open for others to find an answer in case they ever need it.

I simply saved the file to a temp file and then ran the file instead of attempting to run individual lines

```
def fileWriter(array, file):
    f = open(file, 'w+')
    for item in array:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)

os.system('python3 temp.py')
```

works for me